# Generating sub-lists of a string containing keywords in python

Tags: python, list

Hi I have a string in a python script as

```
cp_map = "Valid:\nOP_1\nOP_2\nOP_3\nInvalid:\nOP_4\nOP_5\nUnused:\nOP_6\nOP_7"
```

In this buffer, I want to separate the parameters after a keyword, like, OP_1,OP_2,OP_3 after keyword "Valid". Each set of parameters which follows must be keept in a seperate list, e.g. OP_4, OP_5 must be in another list and OP_6, OP_7 must be in another list . So I neeed to seperate the list and create three seperated lists for valid , invalid or unused operations

I have converted the string to list by spliting it with '\n' like

```
cp_map.split('\n')
```

so I got list

```
cp_map = [u'Valid:', u'OP_1', u'OP_2', u'OP_3', u'Invalids:', u'OP_4'..............]
```

Please help me on creating multiple valid, invalid and unused operation lists.

Comment: seems like you are asking several questions - it would be nice to "accept" the most fitting one and rate the useful ones positively - this encourages others to answer questions in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
cp_map = "Valid:\nOP_1\nOP_2\nOP_3\nInvalid:\nOP_4\nOP_5\nUnused:\nOP_6\nOP_7"
one_list = cp_map.split('\n')
sub_list, multi_lists = [], []
for item in one_list:
    if 'unused' in item.lower() or 'valid' in item.lower() or 'invalid' in item.lower():
        if sub_list:
            multi_lists.append(sub_list)
        sub_list = []
    sub_list.append(item)
multi_lists.append(sub_list)
print multi_lists
```

prints

```
[['Valid:', 'OP_1', 'OP_2', 'OP_3'], ['Invalid:', 'OP_4', 'OP_5'], ['Unused:', 'OP_6', 'OP_7']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either iterate through the list and fill the required sub-lists, or use list.index to find the indices of the keywords "Valid", Invalid", "Unused", and use slicing notation to split the list:

```
cp_map = [u'Valid:', u'OP_1', u'OP_2', u'OP_3', u'Invalid', u'OP_4', 'Unused', 'OP_n']
v_map = cp_map[1 : cp_map.index("Invalid")]
i_map = cp_map[cp_map.index("Invalid") + 1 : cp_map.index("Unused")]
u_map = cp_map[cp_map.index("Unused") + 1 : ]

print(v_map, i_map, u_map)
```

Comment: Brute-forcing :) *I* would suggest `re`

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure of the structure and keywords:

```
token = '!*!'
cp_map = "Valid:\nOP_1\nOP_2\nOP_3\nInvalid:\nOP_4\nOP_5\nUnused:\nOP_6\nOP_7"
cp_map = cp_map.replace(':\n',':')
cp_map = cp_map.replace('\nInvalid', token + 'Invalid')
cp_map = cp_map.replace('\nUnused', token + 'Unused')
cp_map = cp_map.replace('\n',',')
cp_map = cp_map.split(token)
y = {key:op.split(',') for key, op in (cp.split(':') for cp in cp_map)}
valid = y['Valid']
unused = y['Unused']
invalid = y['Invalid']

>>> y
{'Unused': ['OP_6', 'OP_7'], 'Valid': ['OP_1', 'OP_2', 'OP_3'], 'Invalid': ['OP_4', 'OP_5']}
>>>
```